# Setting dynamic crop on sorl.thumnail

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I have added a field on my model for specifying where the thumbnail should crop from, but I can't seem to add that to the template tag.

Here is how I do it now:

```
  {% if entry.main_image.crop_value == "center" %}
   {% thumbnail entry.main_image.image "350x100" crop="center" as im %}
        <a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}" alt=""></a>
    {% endthumbnail %}
  {% elif entry.main_image.crop_value == "top" %}
   {% thumbnail entry.main_image.image "350x100" crop="top" as im %}
        <a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}" alt=""></a>
    {% endthumbnail %}
  {% elif entry.main_image.crop_value == "bottom" %}
   {% thumbnail entry.main_image.image "350x100" crop="bottom" as im %}
        <a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}" alt=""></a>
    {% endthumbnail %}
  {% endif %}
```

This can't be the best way of doing it?

Comment: What happens with `{% thumbnail entry.main_image.image "350x100" crop=entry.main_image.crop_value as im %}`?

Comment: Haha, I had tried crop="entry.main_image.crop_value", but that did not work with the "". Thank you!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable in the template tag:

```
{% thumbnail entry.main_image.image "350x100" crop=entry.main_image.crop_value as im %}
```